# Print a colored string using system call write() in C

Tags: c, colors

Hy guys, I need to write on standard OUTPUT a colored string using the system call write() in C language, is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: It's possible, usually... but exactly how to do it depends a lot on your system and terminal settings.

Comment: @Siguza The shell has nothing to do with it, interpreting color codes is done by the terminal or terminal emulator.

Comment: There's no standard way to do this in C. On Unix you can use the `termcap` library to look up the control sequences to change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned, it depends on your OS / shell. A simple solution for using ANSI-Colors would be:

```
char *str = "\e[32;40m Hello World"; // A green string on a black background
write(fd, str, strlen(str));
```

Note that you have to reset the terminal colors after printing a colored string...

Comment: Thank you, it work for me, using bash on OS X.

Comment: cool, Would you like to select this as a correct answer?